# How to add 10% discount in total with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function calc() {
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("pokok").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('bonus').value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('cut').value);

  total = p + b - c;

  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
<label>Tanggal</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="tanggal" maxlength="11" placeholder="#" required="required"><br>
    
 <label>Gaji Pokok</label>
    <input type="text" name="gajipokok" id="pokok" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
 
 <label>Total Bonus</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalbonus" id="bonus" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
 
 <label>Potongan</label>
    <input type="text" name="potongan" id="cut" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
  
 <label>Total Gaji</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="total">
 
 <label>PPh Pasal 21</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="">


  
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Hello I have javascript calculation where `total = p + b - c;`

so I'm planning to add after reach total part

total discount 10% but didn't affect my total number but just for notif how much is 10% after I get total price.

Going to add var d as discount for pph pasal 21

So what I think its like this for example

(p)500+(b)600-(c)100 = (total)1000

after total appear

in 10% discount part showing is "100" not "900"

Comment: Your snippet was error bro, 
Could you explain clear result that you expected ?

Comment: How would you do it with basic pen and paper, not much different in code.

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the discount as variable d, and subtract it from the total.

```js
function calc() {
  var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("pokok").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('bonus').value);
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('cut').value);

  var total = (p + b + c)*0.9;

  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
<label>Tanggal</label><br>
<input type="date" name="tanggal" maxlength="11" placeholder="#" required="required"><br>

<label>Gaji Pokok</label>
<input type="text" name="gajipokok" id="pokok" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">

<label>Total Bonus</label>
<input type="text" name="totalbonus" id="bonus" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">

<label>Potongan</label>
<input type="text" name="potongan" id="cut" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">

<label>Total Gaji</label>
<input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="total">

<label>PPh Pasal 21</label>
<input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="">

<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

EDIT: As @moodseller mentioned, you can also just get 90% of the total value. It's much cleaner.

Comment: Instead of declaring a new variable to get the amount of discount and only then subtracting it from the total we can hop over a step and just multiply the total by .9: `total*0.9`

Comment: Also `x - x*0.1 = x*(1 - 0.1) = x*0.9`

Comment: Good one @moodseller

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for algebra 101 lesson hah. A simple 90% would've made sense

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the information. Sorry I'm still new learning JS.

Comment: @Skyest Sure thing. Please mark this question as answered so people know in the future. If you're feeling generous please upvote as well!

Answer (score 1):

Try (we use extra `+` to cast string to number)

```
function calc() {    
  total.value = (+pokok.value + +bonus.value - cut.value) * 0.9;
}
```

```js
function calc() {
  total.value = (+pokok.value + +bonus.value - cut.value) * 0.9;
}
```

```html
<label>Tanggal</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="tanggal" maxlength="11" placeholder="#" required="required"><br>
    
 <label>Gaji Pokok</label>
    <input type="text" name="gajipokok" id="pokok" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
 
 <label>Total Bonus</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalbonus" id="bonus" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
 
 <label>Potongan</label>
    <input type="text" name="potongan" id="cut" maxlength="20"  required="required" onkeyup="calc()">
  
 <label>Total Gaji</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="total">
 
 <label>PPh Pasal 21</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalgaji" maxlength="50"  required="required" id="">


  
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You're just need to add,

total = (p + b - c) * 0.1;

Very simple.
In the future, put the discount value as a variable. Avoid hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. I'll keep note on that.